# How can I set a theme for all profiles in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal

I have been experimenting with the new Windows Terminal and I would like to set some properties for all profiles (PowerShell, Cmd, Azure Cloud Shell). 
Specifically, I want to theme each terminal profile with the same color scheme, padding, etc.

```
{
    "colorScheme": "One Half Dark",
    "fontFace": "Cascadia Code",
    "padding": "20"
}
```

I had to add these lines to each profile. Is there a way to specify it only once for all profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your profile is created by old version windows terminal. You can backup your profile(I lost my profile on last updating) and update it.

The new profile has changed to `settings.json`. The `profiles` in `settings.json` has `defaults` and `list` settings. What you need is in `defaults`.

[image]

Comment: You are right! At the time I asked the question that was the existing schema and I doubt there was an option to add defaults :) I have updated my Windows Terminal and it works like a charm!